# it failed when tried to get host name using python

Tags: python-2.7

```
socket.getfqdn()
```

and the result is ok,return sjs_88_78
and then

```
socket.gethostbyname('sjs_88_78')
```

it will socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
is it env issue?how to fix it?

BTW,i run on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

Comment: You'll need to give us more information. Are you running this in a virtualenv, what system are you using, etc. If possible, provide the full stack trace for the error. What happens if you run `socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())`?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Comment: i run on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

Comment: And if you run `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` does it give the same error?

Comment: yes ,the same error

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there are some wrong characters in the name in the second command?

gaierror stands for "getadressinfo error". I saw this error in a case when I had some wrong character in my hostname. In my case that was an additional space that I wrongly copied and paste...
Not sure that it's your case as well... but just for information.

Also, it's interesting  if a invisible return character could provoke this. Like difference between Unix and Windows return character...

Comment: from the result it seem ok

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you don't have a proper address-to-host mapping set up on your server. From the Python socket docs:

"If you want to know the current machine’s IP address, you may want to use gethostbyname(gethostname()). This operation assumes that there is a valid address-to-host mapping for the host, and the assumption does not always hold."

https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gethostname